# vuejs-paginate - switch to page 1 active class when pressing the navbar brand

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I'm using this handy pagination tool called [vuejs-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-paginate) and it works just fine in terms of functionality when I click each individual *page item*, but when I press the navbar brand (which switches to page 1), the pagination tool does not switch the active class to page 1 and the active class just remains on the page you were previously at.

Here's my pagination code:

```
<template>
    <section role="region" class="paginate py-md-5 py-4" id="paginate">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <paginate
                        :page-count="20"
                        :click-handler="clickCallback"
                        :prev-text="'<'"
                        :next-text="'>'"
                        :container-class="'pagination'"
                        :page-class="'page-item'"
                        :page-link-class="'page-link'"
                        :next-class="'page-item'"
                        :next-link-class="'page-link'"
                        :prev-class="'page-item'"
                        :prev-link-class="'page-link'"
                        class="justify-content-center mb-0"
                    >
                    </paginate>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        clickCallback(pageNum) {
            this.$router.push({
                path: `/page/${pageNum}`
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

I was thinking of using some sort of way to programmatically *click* the first page item of the pagination when clicking on the navbar brand, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging, I found out that it was actually *where* I had placed my pagination component. In my Nuxt app, I had put it inside default *layouts*. This means that when I had clicked on the navbar brand to go to the first page, the pagination did not *remount*. So what I did to resolve the problem was to transfer my pagination component to its individual *pages*. Now, when I switch from route to route, the active class will change because the pagination component remounts to react to the changes.